# Experiencing duplicate insert of data into SQL Server database in Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, blazor, .net-6.0

**Problem Description**

I am facing a problem with my Entity Framework Core application where it inserts data into the database twice when I expect it to insert it only once. I've tried to isolate the issue as much as possible and here's the relevant code.

I have an Entity Framework Core application in Blazor with a `Transaction` model, a `TransactionDocument` model, and a `TransactionItem` model. When I try to create and save a new `Transaction` with a related `TransactionDocument` and `TransactionItem`, the data gets inserted twice into the database.

**Code samples**

Here is the relevant code:

Razor page `TransactionsCreate.razor`:

```cs
@page "/TransactionsCreate"
@using Aneta.Models
@using Aneta.Data

@code {
    [Inject]
    private DsaClusterContext? Context { get; set; }
    [Inject]
    private UnitOfWork? UnitOfWork { get; set; }

    private Transaction _transaction;
    private TransactionDocument _transactionDocument;
    private TransactionItem _transactionItem;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (UnitOfWork == null || Context == null)
            return;

        try
        {
            // Create and configure the transaction
            _transaction = new Transaction
            {
                MunicipalityName = "Digos City",
                BarangayName = "Zone 3",
            };

            // Create and configure the document
            _transactionDocument = new TransactionDocument
            {
                PunongBarangayName = "Aidre Cabrera",
                BarangayTreasurerName = "Trisha Talagtag"
            };

            // Create and configure the item
            _transactionItem = new TransactionItem
            {
                Amount = 500,
                Cost = 58,
                Particulars = "Jasmine Rice",
                Price = 58,
                Quantity = 55,
                UnitName = "KG"
            };

            // Establish the relationships
            _transaction.TransactionDocuments.Add(_transactionDocument);
            _transactionDocument.Transaction = _transaction;
            _transactionDocument.TransactionItems.Add(_transactionItem);
            _transactionItem.Document = _transactionDocument;

            // Start a unit of work and add the transaction to the repository
            UnitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(Context);
            UnitOfWork.Transaction.Add(_transaction);

            // Save all changes
            await UnitOfWork.CompleteAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exceptions as needed
        }
        finally
        {
            if (UnitOfWork != null)
            {
                UnitOfWork.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`UnitOfWork` class:

```cs
using Aneta.Data.Repositories;
using Aneta.Models;

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly DsaClusterContext? _context;

    public UnitOfWork(DsaClusterContext? context)
    {
        _context = context;
        Transaction = new SqlRepository<Transaction>(_context);
        TransactionDocuments = new SqlRepository<TransactionDocument>(_context);
        // Other repository initializations...
    }

    // Repository properties...

    public int Complete()
    {
        return _context!.SaveChanges();
    }
    
    public async Task<int> CompleteAsync()
    {
        return await _context?.SaveChangesAsync()!;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

`Transaction` model class:

```cs
public partial class Transaction
{
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public string? MunicipalityName { get; set; }
    public string? BarangayName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TransactionDocument> TransactionDocuments { get; set; } = new List<TransactionDocument>();
}
```

`TransactionDocument` model class:

```cs
public partial class TransactionDocument
{
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public int? TransactionId { get; set; }
    public string? PunongBarangayName { get; set; }
    public string? BarangayTreasurerName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AbstractQuotation> AbstractQuotations { get; set; } = new List<AbstractQuotation>();
    public virtual ICollection<PurchaseOrder> PurchaseOrders { get; set; } = new List<PurchaseOrder>();
    public virtual ICollection<PurchaseRequest> PurchaseRequests { get; set; } = new List<PurchaseRequest>();
    public virtual Transaction? Transaction { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TransactionItem> TransactionItems { get; set; } = new List<TransactionItem>();
}
```

**Issue**

The problem is that when I run this code, it inserts all the data into the database twice, which is not the expected behavior. I want to figure out why and how to prevent this.

**Environment**

- EF Core version: 7.0.11
- Database provider: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
- Target framework: .NET 6.0
- Operating system: Windows 11
- IDE: JetBrains Rider

I am new to this and am still learning how it works. I appreciate any help or insights you can provide to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are adding relationship on both ends. You only need to set relationship once. Either on the parent or child entity. Never on both.

Following code should do the trick.

```cs
@page "/TransactionsCreate"
@using Aneta.Models
@using Aneta.Data

@code {
    [Inject]
    private DsaClusterContext? Context { get; set; }
    [Inject]
    private UnitOfWork? UnitOfWork { get; set; }

    private Transaction _transaction;
    private TransactionDocument _transactionDocument;
    private TransactionItem _transactionItem;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (UnitOfWork == null || Context == null)
            return;

        try
        {
            // Create and configure the transaction
            _transaction = new Transaction
            {
                MunicipalityName = "Digos City",
                BarangayName = "Zone 3",
            };

            // Create and configure the document
            _transactionDocument = new TransactionDocument
            {
                PunongBarangayName = "Aidre Cabrera",
                BarangayTreasurerName = "Trisha Talagtag",
                Transaction = _transaction
            };

            // Create and configure the item
            _transactionItem = new TransactionItem
            {
                Amount = 500,
                Cost = 58,
                Particulars = "Jasmine Rice",
                Price = 58,
                Quantity = 55,
                UnitName = "KG",
                Document = _transactionDocument
            };

            // Start a unit of work and add the transaction to the repository
            UnitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(Context);
            UnitOfWork.Transaction.Add(_transaction);

            // Save all changes
            await UnitOfWork.CompleteAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exceptions as needed
        }
        finally
        {
            if (UnitOfWork != null)
            {
                UnitOfWork.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```